# How to access ViewController from Storyboard initialVC(ContainerView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, storyboard, uicontainerview

I have ran into small problem. I have Storyboard With:

ContainerVC(with ContainerView) -(container is linked to)> - NavigationController -> LogInVC (with delegate).

I want to access that LogInVC

```
UIStoryboard *logIn = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LogIn" bundle:nil];
LogInViewController *logInVc = [logIn instantiateInitialViewController];
```

This code gives me access to ContainerVC and I'm not able to set delegate. When I'm trying to use:

```
LogInViewController *logInVc = [logIn instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([LogInViewController class])];
```

It gives me access to logInVc but without Container and NavigationController(they are needed).
How I can access LogInViewController from storyboard with Container and Nav controller added? Is there anyway to do that using storyboard? Or I have to manually initiate ContainerView, and add LoginVC embed in NavigationController into Container?

Answer (score 0):

After your ContainerVC's view will be loaded (for example in viewDidLoad:) you can access LogInVC with:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [self.childViewControllers firstObject]; 
UIViewController *loginVC = [nav.viewControllers firstObject];
```

then you can do whatever you want with loginVC, for example cast it to LogInViewController and set delegate

```
[(LogInViewController *)loginVC setDelegate:*delegate*];
```

p.s. with [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LogIn" bundle:nil]; you create new storyboard, maybe it's will be enough to get storyboard of some already created viewcontroller, if your application starts from storyboard